# Graphs with different nodes and degrees

Tags: graph-theory

I need to give an example of an undirected graph with the following scenarios:-

1) 6 nodes, each node having degree 3

2) 6 nodes, each having degree 4

3) 7 nodes, each having degree 2 and consisting of exactly 2 connected components.

I am able to get the 1st one, by using a hexagon shape. But for (2) and (3) does anybody have a hint. Also let me know if my attempt for (1) is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: 3: two cycles. Remove a cycle from a $K_6$ for 2.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Removing a cycle from $K_6$would give degrees of 3 rather than 4. Removing an asterisk instead would work.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Quite right.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Thanks for your inputs, Accordingly I have drawn 2 possible diagrams in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As response from the comments I am drawing the possible diagrams for the same:

(2)  6 nodes, each having degree 4

[image]

(3) 7 nodes, each having degree 2 and consisting of exactly 2 connected components.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For 2, take $K_6$ (all degrees are $5$) and remove three disjoint edges.

For 3: use two disjoint cycles, on $7$ points.